# What does the $^*$ operator do in the theory of parsing?

Tags: regular-languages, compilers, parsers

I'm currently reading through Aho's "Theory of parsing, translation and compiling" on my own and I got a bit confused about the closure operator on language $L$ with alphabet $\Sigma$ ($L^*$). The book defines it recursively as follows:

\begin{align*}
1)\ L^0&=\{e\}\\
2)\ L^n&=LL^{n-1}\quad \text{for } n\ge1\\
3)\ L^*&=\bigcup_{n\ge0}{L^n}
\end{align*}

What sort of set does this operation define? It seemed to me that it defines something like "the set of all possible concatenations of strings of language $L$". There wasn't an actual example in the chapter, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what you describe: $L^*$ contains all possible *finite* concatenations of words in L, including the empty word. This operator is known as the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), it is fundamental in the theory of regular languages and more generally of grammars.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. As an example, suppose your alphabet was $\sum = \{a,b\}$ and and you wanted to represent the set of all strings over $\sum$ where every $a$ is immediately followed by a $b$. Then $\{ab , b\}^*$ would give you such a set of strings since it contains exactly all the possible finite concatenations of $ab$ and $b$. If you're familiar with regex expressions, then it is very similiar to the $*$ operator used in that context.